# Using environmental variables in bash while executing python script?

Tags: python, bash, environment-variables

I exported variable in local environment, and need to pass that variable into bash script, which in turn will need to run python script using that env.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
export API_TOKEN=836176e9b6ce
sudo python script.py --pretty
```

Right now I am getting following:

```
Could not find values for Program api_token.
They must be specified via either ini file, command line argument (--api-token),
or environment variables (API_TOKEN)
```

Is it possible to achieve?

Comment: It's hard to answer this without seeing the script.py code.   Is the message you posted coming from bash or python?   Are you reading API_TOKEN in the python code?   A lot more information is needed to answer this.

Comment: @bluegreen - yes, it was reading token in the python code - and the message was coming from python script - solution and flag suggested by janos fixed the issue

Answer (score 3):

The environment you set in the script is not passed through to the command executed by `sudo`. To preserve environment variables, use the `-E` flag:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
export API_TOKEN=836176e9b6ce
sudo -E python script.py --pretty
```